# Finding the fourth point of a perfect square (without knowing order of points)

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry, quadrilateral

When i was writing my programming project the other day i ran into an interesting problem that i couldn't solve, i spent a while trying solutions with absolute values but none of that worked.

Here's the problem:

[image]

I saw a similar problem on this site: [Finding the fourth vertex of a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738973/finding-the-fourth-vertex-of-a-square) 
But my problem differs in the fact that you cannot immediately know the diagonal of the square since the points are given in a random order.

Is this problem even possible? And if not why not?

Comment: If you have any three corners of a square in the plane the points have to be of the form $(a,b), (a,c), (d,b)$, where we can assume $a\neq d$ and $b\neq c$.  Your new point will have the form $(d,c)$.  You just need to check which components match up.

Comment: @DMcMor that is the solution i used in my programming project, (but it uses many if-statements and is not a formula). I'm thinking there may be a vector solution though

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with just a formula. Any formula $f(A,B,C)$ of the three vertices that returned the fourth would have to be symmetric with one swap of two arguments but not another, so you'd have to know which input point was at the corner where the two known edges met before you could apply it. You can find that out only with some "if" logic applied to the coordinates.

Comment: Agreed, since you don't know the order of the point, I don't think you will be able to find a vector solution.  Depending on the language you're using, you may be able to encode the points in such a way as to streamline your code and eliminate some if statements, but that's probably the best you can do.

Comment: @amd my reasoning was that if you randomly decide vectors, such as (v1 - v2) and (v3 - v2) even if you dont know which ones they are you could get the angle between them and possibly use that to multiply by in the final formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u,v,w\in\mathbb R^2$ be the three known vertices (we don't require the four sides of the square to be parallel to the $x$-axis or $y$-axis) and $c$ be the centre of the square. Then $c$ is also the centre of the unique circumcircle of the square. That is, $c$ is the unique solution of $\|u-c\|^2 = \|v-c\|^2 = \|w-c\|^2$. Expanding the squared norms, we get
$$
2c^T\pmatrix{u-v&v-w}
= (\|u\|^2-\|v\|^2,\ \|v\|^2-\|w\|^2).
$$
Thus
$$
c^T=\frac12(\|u\|^2-\|v\|^2,\ \|v\|^2-\|w\|^2)\pmatrix{u-v&v-w}^{-1}
$$
and the remaining vertex is given by $4c-(u+v+w)$.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, and while it would be far too complicated to calculate in a program efficiently it solves my question perfectly. Nice solution - accepted :P

Answer (score 1):

Possible formulas are
$$
x_4 = 2\max(x_1,x_2,x_3)+2\min(x_1,x_2,x_3)-(x_1+x_2+x_3) \\
y_4 = 2\max(y_1,y_2,y_3)+2\min(y_1,y_2,y_3)-(y_1+y_2+y_3) 
$$
Reasoning: There is at least one vertex on the left side and one vertex on the right side among $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$. Therefore, we can calculate the sum of all x-coodinates in two different ways, either as $2\max(x_1,x_2,x_3)+2\min(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ or as $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$.

Comment: this is a clever solution - upvoted

Answer (score 0):

The three distances among the points will always be $L$, $L$ and $L\sqrt{2}$. The two furthest apart are on a diagonal. With that information you can easily find the fourth vertex. The configuration can start out in any dimension. The three points will determine the plane of the square. The square can have any orientation in that plane.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require analysis of the three points if possible